# how to extract this data in yii2 mysql

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

The data to be extracted are:

```
->select('ingreso.idingreso', 'ingreso.fecha_hora', 'persona.nombre', 'ingreso.tipo_comprobante', 'ingreso.serie_comprobante', 'ingreso.num_comprobante', 'ingreso.impuesto', 'ingreso.estado', 'SUM("ingreso.cantidad*precio_cantidad") AS total')
```

the relationships of the models in the tables:

table "ingreso"

```
   public function relations()
    {
        return array(
            'didingreso' => array(self::HAS_MANY,'detalle_ingreso', 'idingreso'),
            );
    }
```

table "detalle_ingreso"

```
 public function relations()
    {
        return array(
            'ingres' => array(self::HAS_ONE,'ingreso', 'idingreso'),
            'articulo' => array(self::HAS_ONE,'articulo', 'idarticulo'),
            );
    }
```

table "articulo"

```
 public function relations()
{
    return array(
        'idproveed' => array(self::HAS_MANY,'ingreso', 'idproveedor'),          
        );
}
```

table "persona"

```
public function relations()
{
    return array(
        'idproveed' => array(self::HAS_MANY,'ingreso', 'idproveedor'),          
        );
}
```

without the relationships I tried to do this:

```
 $table = Ingreso::find()
                ->innerJoinWith('persona', 'ingreso.idproveedor = persona.idpersona')
                ->innerJoinWith('detalle_ingreso', 'ingreso.idingreso = detalle_ingreso.idingreso')
                ->select('ingreso.idingreso', 'ingreso.fecha_hora', 'ingreso.nombre', 'ingreso.tipo_comprobante', 'ingreso.serie_comprobante', 'ingreso.num_comprobante', 'ingreso.impuesto', 'ingreso.estado', 'SUM("detalle_ingreso.cantidad*detalle_ingreso.precio_venta") AS total')
                ->andWhere(["estado" => 'A'])                                               
                ->orderBy(['ingreso.idingreso' => SORT_DESC])
                ->groupBy(['ingreso.idingreso', 'ingreso.fecha_hora', 'ingreso.nombre', 'ingreso.tipo_comprobante', 'ingreso.serie_comprobante', 'ingreso.num_comprobante', 'ingreso.impuesto', 'ingreso.estado']);
```

these are my tables:
[image: tables]

the error that throws me apparently is when trying to access the result and is the following:
[image: error]

thanks for your help.

Comment: are you sure $model contains all result set?

Comment: Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => persona ) [1] => ingreso.idproveedor = persona.idpersona [2] => INNER JOIN ) [1] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => detalle_ingreso ) [1] => ingreso.idingreso = detalle_ingreso.idingreso [2] => INNER JOIN ) ) [select] => Array ( [0] => ingreso.idingreso ) [selectOption] => ingreso.fecha_hora [distinct] => [from] =>[groupBy] =>Array ( [0] => ingreso.idingreso [1] =>ingreso.fecha_hora [2] => ingreso.nombre [3]=>ingreso.tipo_comprobante [4] =>ingreso.serie_comprobante [5] => ingreso.num_comprobante [6] =>ingreso.impuesto [7] => ingreso.estado )

Comment: are you getting a result with normal SQL query?. coz if data is not there then this error will show up. make all the foreign key relationship to your tables, regenerate the models using gii. using yii2 active record relation data you can get.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Yii2 you should use the relations statements from yii2 activeRecord.

[Here the documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-active-record.html#relational-data)

EDIT:

You should create all realtions that you need individually and then create a mixed query with `with`

**Your Model:**

```
public function getIngreso(){
    return $this->hasMany(Ingreso::className(), ['id' => 'id_ingreso']);
}

public function getDetalleingreso(){
    return $this->hasMany(DetalleIngreso::className(), ['id' => 'id_detalleingreso']);
}
```

**In your controller:**

```
$results = $model->find()->select('foo')->with(['ingreso', 'detalleingreso'])->all();
```

Comment: If the relations I already made in the models of the tables, for example this in the model article: 

  public function relations()
    {
     return array(
      'idproveed' => array(self::HAS_MANY,'ingreso', 'idproveedor'),     
      );
    }

Comment: But in Yii2 if you use the relation as the documentation says you should
(In article model)

public function getIngreso(){
    return $this->hasMany(Ingreso::className(), ['ingresoId' => 'articleId']);
}
Then you only have to do:

$modelArticle->ingreso;
to get an array of Ingresos.

I dont know if this code gonna work because i dont know your exact code.

Comment: If I did when I saw Sageth comment and organized it for this:
public function getDetallement ()
    {
   return $ this-> hasMany (Detailing :: className (), ['id' => 'idingreso']);
    }
The query is to do 2 join to 2 tables, and bring the data that matches 2 ids.  The data that I need to obtain are 'idingreso', 'idproveedor', 'date_home' ... of the table 'ingreso'. And 'cantidad', 'precio_venta' of the table 'detalle_ingreso'. And 'nombre' of the table 'persona'.I clarify that already it implements in the other models the relations according to the documentation.

Comment: following their recommendations in the model 'ingreso' create the 2 functions you mentioned in the answer: getIngreso and getDetalleingreso, in the controller:   
$results = Ingreso::find()->select(['idingreso', 'idproveedor', 'fecha_hora', 'tipo_comprobante', 'serie_comprobante', 'num_comprobante', 'impuesto', 'estado', 'cantidad'])
 ->innerJoinWith(['ingreso', 'detalleingreso'])
 ->where(['estado'=> 'A'])
->all();
when trying to get a data from table "detailingreso" example: amount I get error sql: Syntax error or access violation: 1066 Not unique table/alias: 'ingreso'.thanks.